# adding the delete fuction to orocommerce symfony datagrid

Tags: symfony, datagrid, orocrm, orocommerce

so today i would like to add the delete function for my datagrid, my datagrid is looking like this now:

```
datagrids:
  document-grid:
    source:
      type: orm
      query:
        select:
          - document.id
          - document.name
          - document.file
        from:
          - { table: LeadsBundle:document, alias: document}
    columns:
      id:
        label: ID
        frontend_type: integer
      name:
        label: Name
      file:
        label: File
    sorters:
      columns:
        id:
          data_name: document.id
        name:
          data_name: document.name
        file:
          data_name: document.file
    filters:
      columns:
        id:
          type: number
          data_name: document.id
        name:
          type: string
          data_name: document.name
        file:
          type: string
          data_name: document.file

    properties:
      id: ~
      update_link:
        type: url
        route: document_update
        params:
          - id


    actions:
      update:
        type:          navigate
        label:         Update
        link:          update_link
        icon:          edit
        acl_resource:  document_update
```

The update is completely working and now so want to add the delete function can someone help me out? I have tried it from some documentations but I didn't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Delete action can appear automatically in a data-grid, but you should make an entity configurable and specify the [routeName](https://doc.oroinc.com/backend/configuration/annotation/config/#routename) entity config option.

Otherwise, you should implement the action manually and add it in the same way as the update action.